# How can I defeat the Go optimizer in benchmarks?

Tags: performance, go, optimization, performance-testing

In Rust, you can use the [`black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/test/fn.black_box.html) function to force the compiler to

1. assume that the function's argument is used (forcing it not to optimize away code that generates that value)
2. not be able to inspect how its return value is produced (preventing it from doing constant-folding and other such optimizations).

Is there a similar facility in Go (to accomplish either task)?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a similar facility in Go (to accomplish either task)?

No.

If you want to use a result: Assign to an exported global.

Comment: This is insufficient for benchmarking. It doesn't prevent, for instance, constant folding away the function arguments, or removing the benchmark loop.

Comment: @Veedrac The answer is a simple "No", there is no reliable, documented, working way to do either task. Different compilers might behave different here. But a (currently ) working (for gc and gcc) way to prevent the benchmark loop being removed is assigning to a global.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `runtime.KeepAlive` is recommended, as per the following Github issue. Unfortunately, it's unclear whether anything exists for function arguments, or whether `KeepAlive` is even guaranteed to work.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27400